# Calculate the length of the arc of the curve - I do not quite understand the condition

Tags: integration

Calculate the arc length of the curve $x = \alpha \cos^3{t} $; $ y = \alpha \sin^3{t} $; $ 0 \leqslant t \leqslant \frac {\pi} {2} $.

The question is, what is $\alpha$ or $a$? Parameter?

I do not quite understand why the condition is so given.

Comment: yes $a$ is parameter

Comment: This curve is an astroid. $\alpha$ is a parameter. The restriction to $(0,\pi/2)$ is clear when you see the curve (one arc among four). For the computation of the length, see : https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Length_of_Arc_of_Astroid

Comment: Yes, it is a parameter, so the curve is homothetic to the standard astroid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parametrization of astroid curve ( it has maximum radii fitting in a circle radius $a$ on x- and y- axes). Parameter $t$ and maximum radius at cusps is $a$. Polar coordinates of a point

$$ (\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, t )$$

$$ x^{\frac23} +y^{\frac23}=a^{\frac23} $$

is given as

$$x = a\cos^3{t} ;y = a \sin^3{t}\,\,; $$

One of four arcs in first quadrant has limits in the interval

$$ 0 \leqslant t \leqslant \frac {\pi} {2} $$

Standard method to find arc is

$$ s = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{\dot x^2+\dot y^2 }\, dt $$

which calculates to $3a/2$ for one quadrant and 6a for quadrants as mentioned in link given by Jean Marie.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Right, I did not want to repeat steps you gave in the link. The OP had problem at the start itself, to which I addressed. D'Accord?